# Get invalid parameters from commandline parser

Tags: c#, console-application, command-line-parser

I use the commandline parser nuget.

```
var options = new Options();
bool isInputValid = CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options);
```

How do I get the parameters which are invalid?

Comment: Which version you of CommandLine parser nuget you're using?

Comment: The latest!      ......

Comment: <package id="CommandLineParser" version="1.9.71" targetFramework="net45" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `1.9.71` I dont' see any option where you can fetch the invalid tokens from arguments after parsing. But if you upgrade to -pre release version i.e.

```
<package id="CommandLineParser" version="2.0.275-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
```

This version gives flexibility to do more with parsed results. So you can easily find the invalid token like below:

```
 var result = CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);

 result.MapResult(
        options =>
        {
            // Do something with optios
            return 0;
        },
        errors =>
        {
            var invalidTokens = errors.Where(x => x is TokenError).ToList();
            if(invalidTokens != null)
            {
                invalidTokens.ForEach(token => Console.WriteLine(((TokenError)token).Token));
            }

            return 1;
        });
```

Comment: Before someone gets crazy about different version code, that works => foreach (var error in errors.OfType<NamedError>())
                       {
                          Console.WriteLine("The parameter: '{0}' s not correct!", error.NameInfo);
                       }
                       return 1;